# Processing observable array of viewmodels with progressbar and knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I was trying to figure out how to do such thing like automatically process observable array of some viewmodels on server and let it update jquery ui progressbar one by one, i came up with following code :)

```
<div data-bind="progressBar: { value: progressValue, max: ViewModels().length }" style="width: 100%">
</div>

ko.bindingHandlers.progressBar = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            $(element).progressbar({
                    value: false,
                    max: ko.unwrap(value.max)
                });
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            $(element).progressbar("option", "value", ko.unwrap(value.value));
        }
    }

function ViewModel(model) {
        var self = this;
        ko.mapping.fromJS(JSON.parse(model), {}, self);

        self.progressValue = ko.observable(0);
        ko.computed(function () {
            if (self.ViewModels().length > 0) {
                var first = self.ViewModels()[0];
                $.ajax({
                    //send first viewmodel on server and do something with it
                    success: function (result) {
                        self.ViewModels.remove(first);
                        self.progressValue(self.progressValue() + 1);
                    }
                });
            }
        })
    }
```

What do you think about this approach when computed is called recursively? Maybe you dont see any real usage but if, how would you do that other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs say:

> Knockout will not restart evaluation of a computed while it is already evaluating

[(read more here)](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#note_why_circular_dependencies_arent_meaningful)

so if it was really recursive you'd have a problem with your approach.

But it's not really recursive in your case, since the `success` callback will only be called later when the server responds (it's *asynchronous*) in a separate execution-stack.

So I think your approach is fine, assuming it gives you the functionality you're looking for.

A simpler way to do it without a computed is just to put it inside a function and call the function from the success callback:

```
        self.progressValue = ko.observable(0);

        sendRemaining();

        function sendRemaining() {    
            if (self.ViewModels().length > 0) {
                var first = self.ViewModels()[0];
                $.ajax({
                    //send first viewmodel on server and do something with it
                    success: function (result) {
                        self.ViewModels.remove(first);
                        self.progressValue(self.progressValue() + 1);
                        sendRemaining();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and note about recursion in computed observables, also another way this could be done is with subscribe to array, but as u said just using function is simpler